# Show that there exists a non-trivial automorphism on $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

> > Let $G$ be a finite group with at least four elements such that $g^2=e$ for all $g \in G$. Show that there is a non-trivial automorphism on $G$.

How do I proceed to prove it? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If $G$ has more than $2$ elements, then there exists a non-trivial automorphism. This is satisfied here. Arturo's proof is quite short, and refers to elements of order $2$.

Comment: I don't understand why every group whose every element is of exponent $2$ is a vector space over a field of $2$ elements. Where is the property of the group used? If some element of $G$ is not of index $2$ then what are the problems? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Dear Debabrata, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855187/an-abelian-group-as-an-mathbb-f-2-vector-space?rq=1) or more generally [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444505/when-can-a-an-abelian-group-be-made-into-a-vector-space-over-bbbf-p) for a good explanation (by Jyrki, take $p=2$).